# GIMP filters for processing scanned crumpled documents

Tags: image-processing, scanning

I happen to routinely need to do the following: Take a page or a piece of paper which has seen some wear (and sometimes tear); which is often printed with toners or ink cartridges running low, or with thermal printing that has somewhat faded; which has been crumpled and only partially straightened out for scanning; and often has some contents on the back side of the paper, or some annoying watermark on the front - and produce an easy-to-read, as straight-as possible version of the printed text.

I do *not* care about color reproduction quality; or extremely fine details - I care about readability of the text, visibility of lines and frames, and if there's an image in there (e.g. a logo) - I want it not to be completely messed up, i.e. a black blob or a completely-faded-out white stain is not good, other than that I'm flexible.

Now, I'm going to ask a separate question about a dedicated application for this, but for now - suppose I want to do this in gimp, because I want finer control over the parameters and maybe some more processing later on.

Are there filters I could get which take on this task?

- They need to be gratis
- Don't really care if they're libre
- Platform shouldn't matter, but if it does - Linux X86_64
- I use gimp 2.8 but am flexible on that (I know 2.10.x versions are out)

Comment: Have you already tried `unpaper` – which is for "improving scans for OCR" preprocessing? Not sure how well it does with "crumpled paper", but worth a try.

Comment: @Izzy: Yes, and it put some white squares on top of some of the image. Not much help.

Comment: Ugh… indeed not if that was the outcome *shrugs* Well, we cannot say we didn't try. Good luck then!